# Layout editor doesn't display custom view when I use a custom font in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, resources, android-custom-view

Layout editor doesn't display a custom view when I use a custom font. However, it works when I run the app.

When I write the line that assigns a typeface it doesn't display the view.

```
textValuePaint = TextPaint().apply {
        textSize = DimensionsUtils.dpToPx(context, 24f)
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.alex_brush)
    }
```

[image: Layout editor doesn't display the custom view]

It also says Path.op() not supported. I don't know if that is related with my problem.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Some operations are not supported in the edit mode so you cannot see them in preview. In order to overcome this, you should run this kind of operations only in runtime. To achieve this you can use isInEditMode() method in your custom view. For example

```
if(!isInEditMode()){
     typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.alex_brush)
}
```